# Javascript creating multidimensional array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm strugling with this for over a day now and can't get it working. I want to create a multidimensional javascript array that hold filter variables that must be pharsed to php for AJAX calls. The goal is to make a product filter and filter out products that don't apply to the filter variables.

The last part is php and I know how to solve that. But I'm struggling with creating a javascript array that holds all the selected filter variables.

I have a `filter_ID` and a `filter_value_ID`. Withing a filter, for example size, there can be different values like S, M, L, XL etc.

So I want a array like this:

```
filterArr = array(
  [4] => array(10,20,30)
  [8] => array(4)
  [20] => array(2,3, 7)
)
```

The array must be filled when a user check a checkbox. I managed it almost, but the problem is that I'm getting `null` items in the array, because I cant get the filterID in the array.

My code is on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VCfjp/

The part where it is going wrong is on line 10, 11, 12:

```
if (!(filterID in filter)) {
  filter[filterID] = [];
}
```

I'm running stuck at the moment. I would know how to do it in PHP, but can't get it working in javascript. Some help is appreciated! Offcourse I've been looking at other threads on the forum, but can't find anything matching.

Comment: try this `var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];`

Comment: rather that why you dont use plain object key : value 
easier

Comment: The array if filled dynamically based on checkboxed the user clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash arrays in JS are defined as object, so use it like this:

`var object = {
    4: [10,20,30],
    8: [4],
    20: [2,3,7]
};`

Just observe what PHP would ouput when issuing:

`echo json_encode(array(
  [4] => array(10,20,30)
  [8] => array(4)
  [20] => array(2,3, 7)
));`

The code you requested:

`jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var hashArray = {};
    $('.myCheckbox').on('change', function() {
        var self = $(this),
            checkboxId = parseInt(self.attr('data-id')), // since you used it as a number above
            checkboxValue = parseInt(self.val()); // since you also used it as a number above
        if (self.is(':checked')) {
            // add to array
            if (!hashArray.hasOwnProperty(checkboxId)) hashArray[checkboxId] = [];
            hashArray[checkboxId].push(checkboxValue);
        }
        else {
            if (hashArray.hasOwnProperty(checkboxId)) {
                // remove from array if it exists
                hashArray[checkboxId].splice(hashArray[checkboxId].indexOf(checkboxValue), 1);
            }
        }
    });
});`

Comment: The problem is that there is no array when the script starts. The array is created based on the user input!

Comment: So start with an empty object and simply add properties to it?

Comment: YES! I think I can do it with that code! Updated my JSFIDDLE and seems to work fine on that one (http://jsfiddle.net/7WKcR/). Now I will try to implement this in my code!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: I posted the wrong JSFIDDLE URL, here is the right one. http://jsfiddle.net/7WKcR/4/