# How do you build function that creates a multi-dimensional array in javascript given an argument that corresponds to the dimension of the array?

Tags: javascript

How do you build function that creates a multi-dimensional array in javascript given an argument that corresponds to the dimension of the array? Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like a homework. Anyway, it doesn't matter if it's multidimensional or what. What are the contents supposed to be?

Comment: You should refer this link may be It help full to you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536380/javascript-creating-multidimensional-array-dynamically